# Writing functions in Eigen that evaluate lazily and don't make copies

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to write a function in Eigen that has good performance. My current code does what I'd like it to do, but I'm basically defining the function in preprocessor definitions per variable. I'm writing a finite difference function (basically numpy's diff()), so if someone could just point me to that, it'd be great, but I also have some similar functions (one that preforms a weighted average instead of a difference) that require me to nevertheless write these functions.
My current code looks something like this (only including relevant parts):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

typedef Eigen::MatrixXd matrix;
const int size = 2048;

matrix temps(size, size) = matrix::Random(size, size);
matrix Kx, Qx, Q;

int main() {
    //timing start
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        #define DIFFX (temps.bottomRows(size - 1) - temps.topRows(size - 1))
        Qx = DIFFX.cwiseProduct(Kx);

        //other code

        #define DIFF2X (Qx.rightCols(size - 2) - Qx.leftCols(size - 2))
        Q.block(0, 1, size, size - 2) += DIFF2X;

        //etc
    }
    //timing stop
}
```

I'd like to refactor the DIFFX into a separate function, eg:

```
template <typename Derived>
inline Derived diffX(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& I) {
    return I.rightCols(I.cols() - 1) - I.leftCols(I.cols() - 1);
}
```

My problem is that when I replace just the first `DIFFX` with `diffX(temps)` I go from a consistent 0.12 seconds per cycle to 0.17 seconds (including all the other operations in the cycle). (this is a tight loop that will have a few tens of these operations, so performance is rather important)

My question is, how do I write functions extending Eigen that 1: don't make useless copies and 2: will do proper lazy evaluation and smart reduction to 3: have the same performance as writing long (non-extensible) inlines

Comment: To avoid a copy in the returned value of diffX, change the return type to `auto`. Requires c++14.

Comment: What are `Kx`, `Qx` and `Q`? In other words: provide a [mcve].